# app.use not working in other class express

Tags: node.js, express

i m try to use app instance in other js file but don't know why it not working, below is sample code (i m using express 4)

app.js

```
    const app = express();
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }) //{
    const urlEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }) //

    app.set('superSecret', config.secret)
    app.disable("x-powered-by")
  //oauth file
   var oauth= require('./services/oauth');

    module.exports = app
```

in service/oauth file index.js

```
 module.export.oauth2app=oauth2app
  const oauth2app =require('../../app')
  oauth2app.use('/',router);  //its not working
```

why oauth2app.use not working in index.js it throw error like oauth2app.use is not function can any body tell me what i m doing wrong

Comment: circular dependency

Comment: @AyushGupta updated still it not working

Comment: Please put your code back the way it was when you first asked it.  That's the code that the answer applies to.  If you need to, you can add additional code after your original (and designate it as something you added after the fact).  Questions should not be a continually changing question.  You ask a question, you get an answer.  If you need to ask another question, you don't edit the original question - you ask another question.

Comment: `module.export.oauth2app=oauth2app` should be `exports`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.  app.js is loading service/oauth/index.js and then that file is attempted to load app.  You can't do that.  The second one that causes the circular loop will return `{}` and thus `{}.use()` won't work.

The usual solution here is to pass the `app` object to your service/oauth/index.js module in an exported module constructor function rather than have it try to load app.

```
    const app = express();
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const jsonParser = bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb' }) //{
    const urlEncoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }) //

    app.set('superSecret', config.secret)
    app.disable("x-powered-by")

    // oauth file 
    // pass app to module constructor function
    require('./services/oauth')(app);
```

And, then in the oauth file, you export a function that is used to initialize the module:

```
// this should get called by whoever loads us and they should
// pass us the app object.
module.exports = function(app) {
      app.use('/', router);
}
```

Comment: Correction - `oauth2app` will be be `{}` not null

Comment: @AyushGupta - Corrected.  I also showed them how to create a module constructor to work around the circular dependency.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for replay i update my question can you tell me will it now work

Comment: @bipin - No, that will not work.  You have to put ALL code that uses the `app` object inside the function you export.  And, please DON'T edit your question that way.  You HAVE to  leave your original question intact with the original code because that original code is what the answers and comments apply to.  You can add new code to the end of your question if you need to clarify something about the original question.  Don't change the original code in your question.  Please put that back the way it was.